# Oracle PIVOT - unused columns affect rollup

Tags: oracle, pivot

I've got a dataset that consists of several key fields, a status, and a count. PIVOT does a nice job of giving me one row per key field combo, with one column per status. Sample below:

```
with dataquery (field1, field2, field3, my_status, statcount) as (
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'XX', 11 from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'YY', 22 from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'ZZ', 33 from dual
), 
pivotquery as (
 SELECT field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    xx_stat_count     AS xx,
    yy_stat_count     AS yy,
    zz_stat_count     AS zz
  FROM dataquery
    PIVOT (
        SUM (statcount) AS stat_count
        FOR (my_status)
        IN ('XX' AS XX,
            'YY' AS yy,
            'ZZ' AS zz
            )
          )
)
select * from pivotquery;
```

This gives the expected results:

```
FIELD1   FIELD2  FIELD3  XX  YY  ZZ
AAA      BBB     CCC     11  22  33
```

If I have extra columns in the data, however, it does not ignore them and roll things up as I had expected. It seems to be trying to use the unused columns as part of the grouping logic, rather than ignoring them. If I change the input to this:

```
with dataquery (field1, field2, field3, my_status, statcount, cnt2, cnt3, cnt4) as (
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'XX', 11, 12, 13, 14 as cnt4 from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'YY', 22, 22, 23, 24 as cnt4  from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'ZZ', 33, 32, 33, 34 as cnt4  from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'YY', 122, 32, 33, 34 as cnt4  from dual
)
```

I get this:

```
FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3  XX  YY   ZZ
AAA    BBB    CCC         22
AAA    BBB    CCC         122  33
AAA    BBB    CCC     11
```

Instead of the expected

```
FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3  XX  YY   ZZ
AAA    BBB    CCC     11  144  33
```

If I change the input data further, so there is no repetition of those other fields, it shows up as 4 lines:

```
with dataquery (field1, field2, field3, my_status, statcount, cnt2, cnt3, cnt4) as (
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'XX', 11, 12, 13, 14 as cnt4 from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'YY', 22, 22, 23, 24 as cnt4  from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'ZZ', 33, 32, 33, 34 as cnt4  from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'YY', 122, 132, 33, 34 as cnt4  from dual
)
```

gives

```
FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3  XX  YY   ZZ
AAA    BBB    CCC         22
AAA    BBB    CCC              33
AAA    BBB    CCC         122  
AAA    BBB    CCC     11
```

Is this expected behavior?

I can work around it, either by adding a subquery beforehand that selects just field1, field2, field3, mystatus and statcount to be processed by the PIVOT, or doing a select / group by afterward that gets rolls things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this expected behavior?

Yes, from the [`SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

> The `pivot_clause` computes the aggregation functions specified at the beginning of the clause. Aggregation functions must specify a `GROUP BY` clause to return multiple values, yet the `pivot_clause` does not contain an explicit `GROUP BY` clause. Instead, the `pivot_clause` performs an implicit `GROUP BY`. The implicit grouping is based on all the columns not referred to in the `pivot_clause`, along with the set of values specified in the `pivot_in_clause`.). If you specify more than one aggregation function, then you must provide aliases for at least all but one of the aggregation functions.

---

To solve it, use a sub-query to only `SELECT` the required columns so that the other columns are not used implicitly as the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
with dataquery (field1, field2, field3, my_status, statcount, cnt2, cnt3, cnt4) as (
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'XX', 11, 12, 13, 14 as cnt4 from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'YY', 22, 22, 23, 24 as cnt4  from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'ZZ', 33, 32, 33, 34 as cnt4  from dual
union
select 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'YY', 122, 132, 33, 34 as cnt4  from dual
)
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3,
       xx_stat_count     AS xx,
       yy_stat_count     AS yy,
       zz_stat_count     AS zz
FROM   (
 SELECT field1,
        field2,
        field3,
        my_status,
        statcount
 FROM   dataquery
)
PIVOT (
  SUM (statcount) AS stat_count
  FOR (my_status) IN (
    'XX' AS XX,
    'YY' AS yy,
    'ZZ' AS zz
  )
);
```

Outputs:

> | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 | XX | YY | ZZ |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | AAA | BBB | CCC | 11 | 144 | 33 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=75cb8848f0951f779a9c194f4316f5fd)*